# Oracle - update same table on which trigger is fired

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have a table temp_table with the following columns
Id number,
name varchar,
Password varchar,
pwd_change_date timestamp

I want to capture the timestamp in pwd_change_date column only when password column is changed.
So basically i want to use update statement inside the trigger to update timestamp value in pwd_change_date column for the same record.

Example
When a password is changed for one user, I want to capture the timestamp value in pwd_change_date for the same record.

I tried with before insert and after insert of password on temp_table, but getting mutation error. Is it allowed in Oracle to update the Same row/table on which trigger is fired?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to update the table again; you can modify the data before it is inserted, with a before-insert row level trigger, e.g.:

```
create trigger trig_pwd_date
before insert or update on temp_table
for each row
when (old.password is null and new.password is not null or new.password != old.password)
begin
  :new.pwd_change_date := systimestamp;
end;
/
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=34f1529185cb41e1578903f4c26e7a9d)

This used the `new` and `old` [correlation names](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-4CF74E99-8859-4AB1-96E7-07898A2ABB9E) to decide if the password value has changed; and the `new` correlation name to assign the system time to the field in the pseudorecord, which becomes the column value when the insert completes.

Hopefully you aren't storing plain-text passwords in your table.

Comment: Bang on!! Thank you Alex for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

SQL> create table temp_table (password varchar2(50), pwd_change_date TIMESTAMP);

Table created.

SQL> create trigger trig_pwd_date
before insert or update on temp_table
for each row
when (old.password is null and new.password is not null or new.password != old.password)
begin
:new.pwd_change_date := systimestamp;
end;  2    3    4    5    6    7
8  /

Trigger created.

Comment: Review:- Please format your code and explain how it differs from other answers .

Answer (score 0):

SQL> set time on
15:28:42 SQL> insert into temp_table values ('23456',sysdate);

1 row created.

15:29:01 SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

15:29:09 SQL> select * from temp_table;

### PASSWORD

### PWD_CHANGE_DATE

12345
21-SEP-20 03.28.02.370377 PM

23456
21-SEP-20 03.29.01.478017 PM