# Oracle statement trigger cant access table values

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

When trying to access table values inside my statement trigger, I get the following error "ID XXX must be declared".

### Table

```
CREATE TABLE testTable(
   id INT,
   store INT,
   amount NUMBER
);
```

### Trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_trigger
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON testTable
    DECLARE
       myID INT;
       myStore INT;
    BEGIN
        myID := id;
        myStore := store;

      IF amount < 3 THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DANGER');
      END IF;

    END;
```

### Error

```
PLS-00201: ID 'id' must be declared
PLS-00201: ID 'store' must be declared
PLS-00201: ID 'amount' must be declared
```

I am new to oracle pl/sql and triggers and have zero clue how to solve this.

Comment: You'd want `:new.id` or `:old.id` (and `:new.store` or `:old.store` and `:new.amount` or `:old.amount`) depending on whether you are trying to get the old value or the new value.  Since this is an `insert or update` trigger, my assumption would be that you want the values being inserted and the values that the `update` statement is updating the row to so you'd want to use the `:new` pseudorecord.

Comment: You are referring to table column names, but the statement trigger doesn't know which row's data you are talking about (or even which table, as it has no context for what those identifiers are supposed to be). If you want to refer to the row being inserted then you should have a row-level trigger; but you seem to have intentionally created a statement-level one.

Comment: But when I use a row trigger, I cant update the table itself because of the mutating table problem

Comment: @Andrew - you can modify the data in the row about to be inserted/updated in a before ... for each row trigger, by assigning values to the `:new.xxx` identifiers. That is not the same as doing an `update` statement within the trigger body. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63997215/266304) was similar, perhaps. That doesn't seem to be what this question is about though...

Comment: But what if I want to write something like: "if amount < 3 Then UPDATE test_table SET amount = 5". Would that work? Writing this gave me a mutating table problem

Comment: If you are going to update the table, rather than changing just the row being modified, then you can't use a row-level trigger and won't have access to the values that were changed.  You could create a compound trigger with a row-level part that writes the row-level data to a collection and a statement-level part that reads the collection.  But that's a decent level of complexity.  You probably just want a row-level trigger that modifies the `:new.amount` field of the row being modified.

Comment: @Andrew - would you really want to update *every row* in the table to 5, based on the value of one row being inserted/updated? That seems unlikely. `if :new.amount < 3 then :new.amount := 5; end if;` would just affect this row.

Comment: Note that if you want to modify the new values, you'd want a before insert row-level trigger.  An after insert trigger can't modify the new values.

Comment: @AlexPoole Yeah you are right, I dont want to update every row, just the ones that are affected. But writing :new.amount := 5 doesnt work, because you cant update new or old values. What would be the alternative.

Comment: @Andrew - like I said, you need a *before* trigger, not an *after* trigger. Then you can update the new values.

Comment: Well, looks like I am going to change the after trigger to the before trigger then.

Answer (score 0):

needs :new for new or update record
Try this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_trigger
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON testTable
DECLARE
    myID      INT;
    myStore   INT;
BEGIN
    myID := :new.id;
    myStore := :new.store;
    IF :new.amount < 3
    THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('DANGER');
    END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need an before trigger and should be for each row so if you have only this:

```
IF amount < 3 THEN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DANGER');
      END IF;
```

the row will be inserted and you will get also the message but i don t think you want to insert the row so one way it could be this:

```
CREATE TABLE testTable(
   id INT,
   store INT,
   amount NUMBER
);

set serveroutput on size unlimited
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON testTable
    FOR EACH ROW
/*DECLARE
    myID      INT;
    myStore   INT;*/
BEGIN
    -- myID := :new.id;
    -- myStore := :new.store;
    IF :new.amount < 3 THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Danger-Amount should be greater than or equal to 3');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

I have commented the declaration part because the variabiles are not been used.

Test the trigger:

```
INSERT INTO testTable (id, store, amount) VALUES (1, 101, 5); --this row will be inserted
INSERT INTO testTable (id, store, amount) VALUES (2, 102, 2); --this no
```

Hope it helps.